# Joining two columns value in 1 table and Sort it by ascending Using sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have two kind of discount

```
1.the fixed php
2.the percent %
```

they are different columns in just the same table

the table name is discount, 
the table column is disc_amt, disc_pct

the name of field for description of product is disc_desc

i want to sort this discount in this

description =   1 pesos

description =  1 %s

description = 2 pesos

description=  2 percent

some one can help me??

Comment: try to explain better. A few rows from the original table and an example desires output can help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select two or more fields from the same table (or different tables as well)
wherein each field is sorted by itself like the one below:

SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT disc_amt FROM discount ORDER BY disc_amt),
(SELECT disc_pct FROM discount ORDER BY disc_pct)

I tested this one on sqlite although with a different table and it works.

Given this is what you want. But if you want to include the description column then that is a different story although it's doable but it does not necessarily match row
per row with other fields (e.g. disc_amt and disc_pct).